# How to create several columns with string value in TVSB Table of the Opensearch Dashboards?

Tags: string, visualization, kibana, opensearch

I wanted to a create table in TVSB visualization with information of selected fields. I could only get with aggregations, basically numbers. The column always represents the number. For example: average of risk.keywords but I want to get the risk.keyword itself.

I know that there are different ways like Table visualization or Saved search. However, I need to do it with TVSB Table section.

Please suggest me a solution. Thank you for any help!